# Getting "[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: backward-delete-word" when using ruby-debug with jruby 1.7.0

Tags: jruby, ruby-debug

I get the following output after upgrading to jruby 1.7.0 and using ruby-debug:

```
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: backward-delete-word
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: backward-delete-word
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
(rdb:1)
```

And the debugger doesn't respond and I can only do <CTRL>-Z to exit and kill the process. 
A google search at present for any of those lines turns up zero results at present, so not sure at all where to look.

Comment: I don't think this happens with default configuration. Do you have anything in `~/.rdebugrc`?

Comment: `set autolist

set autoeval

set autoreload

set framefullpath

set frameclassname

set forcestep`

Comment: I'll try and narrow it down now

Comment: I get the same with an empty ~/.rdebugrc

Comment: Anyone?

Even getting this after a reinstall and using rbenv instead of rvm

Comment: jruby 1.7.1 (1.9.3p327) 2012-12-03 30a153b on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909 [darwin-i386]

Comment: Mac OS 10.7.5 11G63, 1.6GHz Intel Core i5, 4GB 1333MHz DDR3

Comment: rbenv 0.3.0, Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Comment: Configured with:/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same problem like that and stumbled upon a workaround. It might work for you too.

When you are prompted with that, press "v" and enter and you are in debugger mode!

Comment: This works for me, thanks Phyo. Would be good to gain some understanding of what it is, but for now at least this is a workaround.
It seems this is the source of the error message
https://github.com/jline/jline2/pull/42/files#L0R256